# Im making this discord.py ecnomy bot and It not giving me any errors but it dosent send the embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

The code I'm using:

```py
@client.command()
async def buy(ctx,item,amount = 1):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    res = await buy_this(ctx.author,item,amount)

    if not res[0]:
        if res[1]==1:
            await ctx.send("That Object isn't there!")
            return
        if res[1]==2:
            await ctx.send(f"You don't have enough money in your wallet to buy {amount} {item}")
            return
        if item in mainshop:
            name = item["name"].lower()
            p = item["price"]
            cost = p*amount
            return
        if cost == cost:

            embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff0000,description = f"{ctx.author.mention} bought {amount} {item} for `{cost}` coins")
            embed.set_author(icon_url = bot_pfp,name = f"Succesful {item} purchase.")
            embed.set_footer(text ="Thank-You for your purchase")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**Details:**

It's not giving me errors and it does buy the item for me...but its not sending the embed..and the embed works if I remove the price variable but I want to keep that. I have tried many things but doesn't seem to work.I would make different if statements for each type of name but that takes too much work and is just hard.
Here's the `buy_this` function:

```py
async def buy_this(user,item_name,amount):
    item_name = item_name.lower()
    name_ = None
    for item in mainshop:
        name = item["name"].lower()
        if name == item_name:
            name_ = name
            price = item["price"]
            break

    if name_ == None:
        return [False,1]

    cost = price*amount

    users = await get_bank_data()

    bal = await update_bank(user)

    if bal[0]<cost:
        return [False,2]

    try:
        index = 0
        t = None
        for thing in users[str(user.id)]["bag"]:
            n = thing["item"]
            if n == item_name:
                old_amt = thing["amount"]
                new_amt = old_amt + amount
                users[str(user.id)]["bag"][index]["amount"] = new_amt
                t = 1
                break
            index+=1 
        if t == None:
            obj = {"item":item_name , "amount" : amount}
            users[str(user.id)]["bag"].append(obj)
    except:
        obj = {"item":item_name , "amount" : amount}
        users[str(user.id)]["bag"] = [obj]        

    with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

    await update_bank(user,cost*-1,"wallet")

    return [True,"Worked"]
```

Comment: there's a return in each if block, maybe thats the reason i guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such an simple indent mistake:

```
        if item in mainshop:
            name = item["name"].lower()
            p = item["price"]
            cost = p*amount
            return
        if cost == cost:

            embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff0000,description = f"{ctx.author.mention} bought {amount} {item} for `{cost}` coins")
            embed.set_author(icon_url = bot_pfp,name = f"Succesful {item} purchase.")
            embed.set_footer(text ="Thank-You for your purchase")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The `if cost == cost:` is not inside of `if item in mainshop` and the last line in `if item in mainshop` is a return so indent the loop - `if cost == cost:` and remove the return inside of `if item in mainshop`

It would be:

```
        if item in mainshop:
            name = item["name"].lower()
            p = item["price"]
            cost = p*amount
            if cost == cost:
                embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff0000,description = f"{ctx.author.mention} bought {amount} {item} for `{cost}` coins")
                embed.set_author(icon_url = bot_pfp,name = f"Succesful {item} purchase.")
                embed.set_footer(text ="Thank-You for your purchase")
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            else:
                await ctx.send("You don't have enough money to buy {name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending the embed only `if not res[0]`, by the indentation. That's probably what's causing the problem. Also, using `if code == code` is useless: might as well not write the `if` statement.

On a side note, you might want to return the item name and price from the `buy_this` function itself to ensure you don't have to loop through the entire `mainshop` vairable again.